# ReactJS: Change placeholder color in a form

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm trying to change the placeholder color to allows the users to know which fields are obligatory or not.

I have an Index.js that load the form:

```
Content = props => {
    const self = this

    return(
      <form
        className="col-12 px-sm-0 px-xs-0"
        onSubmit={e => e.preventDefault()}
        onKeyPress={(e) => {
          if (e.key === 'Enter') {
            e.preventDefault(); //<===== This stops the form from being submitted
          }
        }}
        >
        <Inizio formName={FORM_NAME} />
```

and the Inizio.js

```
export default class Inizio extends Component
{
  constructor(props)
  {
    super(props);
  }

  Fields = [
    {
      name: '$Anagraphics',
      label: 'Dati anagrafici',
      fields: [
        {
          name: 'Anagraphics.Surname',
          col: ["lg-6", 'md-6', 'sm-12'],
          label: "Cognome",
          placeholder: "Cognome",
          placeholderTextColor: "#6495ed",
          required: true,
          validate: FieldValidation.required,
          component: Fields.Text,
          normalize: value => utility.capitalizeEachWord(value)
        },
```

Do you know how can I change the color of placeholder?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to access a particular element of the array use:

```
// Edit property name with your property (e.g. placeholderTextColor)
Field[index].fields[index].${property name}
```

In your case, it would be like this:

```
Fields[0].fields[0].placeholderTextColor = '#value';
```

Answer (score 0):

The color of the placeholder can be changed on an event, like a keyboard click, radio button click etc. Under what situation do you want to change the color of the placeholder? Maybe you can pass it as props to the Inizio component on an event being fired like this:

```
<Inizio formName={FORM_NAME} placeholderColor={color} />
```

the color variable can be a state which is changed when an event is fired.

Comment: I would to show the red placeholder for some fields when the form is loaded

Answer (score 0):

Component.jsx

```
....
<input placeholder="colored placeholder" className="my-input" />
....
```

Component.style.css

```
.my-inpu::placeholder {
    color: #ff0000
}
```